# Простой GWT 2.3 и Maven проект в Eclipse Indigo

Tags: gwt, eclipse

Когда я создаю проект в эклипсе с помощью этих параметров:

*Archetype Group Id - org.codehaus.mojo;
Archetype Artifact Id - gwt-maven-plugin; 
Archetype Version - 2.3.0-1*.

Я получаю очень странные ошибки:

- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.3.0-1:generateAsync (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.3.0-1:i18n (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)
- Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:exploded (execution: default, phase: compile)

И еще некоторые warnings, такие как:

- Implementation of project facet jst.web could not be found. Functionality will be limited.
- Implementation of project facet wst.jsdt.web could not be found. Functionality will be limited.

Вот так выглядит созданный pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.test1</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestWebApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

  <properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.3.0</gwtVersion>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>test</goal>
              <goal>i18n</goal>
              <goal>generateAsync</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see 
          gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
        <configuration>
          <runTarget>TestWebApp.html</runTarget>
          <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
          <i18nMessagesBundle>net.test1.TestWebApp.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exploded</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Я делаю все по инструкциям в интернете. Я перепробовал наверное практически все инструкции по созданию GWT+Maven приложений. Во всех примерах (а все примеры написаны был для старых версий GWT, Eclipse, Maven) все работает, а у меня появляются ошибки.

Как это можно устранить? Как вообще просто создать простой проект на базе GWT с помощью Maven в Эклипсе? Чтобы в нем не было никаких ошибок и варнингов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сменить Eclipse на IDEA. С GWT2.3 во всех IDE косяки повылезали, но IDEA уже исправилась.

Comment: Поставил ИДЕА. Все завелось из коробки! Мало того, это, похоже, любовь с первого взгляда. Спасибо. Не знаю, как вас отблагодарить, не вижу где поставить вам плюс.

Comment: Правда есть кое-что еще непонятное. Все комплируется и запускается, но Инспектор показывает, что есть ошибки в пом.хмл, вот такие:
Cannot resolve directory ''${webappDirectory}''
Cannot resolve directory 'WEB-INF' 
Cannot resolve file 'classes'

И все это на строку в поме:
<build>
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
. . . 
</build>

что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Если это warning, то Инспектор предложит его не показывать (Press Alt+Enter)